# XenServer 7.2 Hot Fix - Can only apply to Pool not Individual Hosts

Tags: xenserver, update, blade-server, patch-management, pool

I'm running **xenserver 7.2** on a few **M620 blade servers**. I'm trying to apply **XS72E004 and 005 patches**. I go to the notification section and select Download/Install next to each patch. I have a **pool** created and if I leave the pool selected I can apply the update. I only want to ***patch each server one at a time*** though. When I try to select one server at a time though the patch is unavailable.

I tried putting the server in **maintenance mode** and that did not work. I tried downloading the **iso and manually selecting it** but not luck. Did Citrix change up the way patches are applied? I'd appreciate any suggestions or input.

Comment: I should mentioned that we upgraded from version 6.5 about 2 months ago. Everything has worked fine but this is the first time we're trying to patch since upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You can try this solution:
In XenCenter after download patch from Tools/Install update, before screen with install, kill XenCenter with TaskManager ( if You use cancel button, patches will be removed from storage).
Patch will be uploaded to hdd of xenserver.
Next from xenserver console list downloaded patches :
xe update-list
note patch uuid and use it in next commmand:
xe update-apply host=XENHOSTNAME uuid=PATCH_UUID

Comment: I appreciate the response. Just so I understand, the update process is ultimately being carried out from the command line then and not through Xen Center, correct?